# Cannot find registry key in WOW64 mode

Tags: c#, registry, wow64

I am using this code to get a key from the registry:

```
RegistryKey mykey = 
      Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Publisher\\Product", true);
```

And the key does exist in the registry under

```
\HKCU\Software\Publisher\Product
```

However, my code is compiled x86 and this is running on a x86_64 machine. So, I reckon I should create the key under

```
\HKCU\Software\WOW6432Node\Publisher\Product
```

however, the key isn't found. How can I change my registry (I cannot change the code) to find this key on a x86_64 machine?

Comment: As far as I have understood your requirement, it would be good if you can create a service/code which would pull the details from the Regular Registry into the WOW6432Node.

Comment: @RamMehta infact, just doing it once manually would already help. Point is that I did that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: No, HKCU isn't redirected like that.  HKLM is.  You will have to look for another explanation.  Like Product actually being a value instead of a key.

Comment: So you mean to say the code is not picking up the value from the registry ?

Comment: @RamMehta yes, the little piece of C# code I provided returns `null`.

Comment: I think you are missing something in the registry you created manually. As @HansPassant said, please give a detailed look one more time.